# Drupal7 managed_file form permissions

Tags: 7, forms, files, media

```
$form['search_results']['file_upload'] = array(
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#title' => t('Thumbnail'),
'#default_value' => variable_get('file_upload'),
'#upload_location' => 'public://uploads/');
```

When using this, should managed_file create folder "uploads" if folder doesn't exists? If folder exists, regular users can't upload to that directory because of folder permissions, how to change that?

Comment: [Securing file permissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) has everything you need to know about file permissions (both what they should be and how to change them)

Comment: I'm creating a module, and I just want to upload images to folder "uploads"

Comment: I'm not sure how can I respond to that - if you read the link above your question will be answered